# rtspsrc is not supported for arm64 iOS Swift Gstreamer library (Xcode 10.1)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, gstreamer, xcode10.1

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: 
  "_gst_plugin_rtspsrc_register", referenced from: 
      _gst_ios_init in gst_ios_init.o 
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)

I am unable to use Gstreamer RTSP plugin in my iOS Swift project as the 
Xcode fails to compile. I want to stream video using rtspsrc. I am getting 
the above compilation error.

I amusing Xcode 10.1, Gstreamer 1.14.4.

Any idea how to solve the above issue???

Answer (score 1):

The `rtspsrc` element is located in the `rtsp` plugin.

Assuming you're basing your code on the GStreamer iOS examples from the [gst-docs examples](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-docs/tree/master/examples/tutorials/xcode%20iOS), then you need to declare and register the `rtsp` plugin using `GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(rtsp)` and `GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(rtsp)` in the appropriate place in `gst_ios_init.m`